# App name removes from url when clicking button to open servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets, web.xml

I need to simply invoke a servlet from html page but when i click a button on html page, then my app name is removed from the url.

I checked the web.xml, it seems fine to me.
I also checked the Servlet by directly providing the target URL in the browser

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <form action="/bomb" method="get">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MySevlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>bomb.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/bomb</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Servlet simply writes a String as a response.

URL before clicking button

```
http://localhost:8080/XYZ/
```

URL after clicking button

```
http://localhost:8080/bomb?
```

But the correct URL should be

```
http://localhost:8080/XYZ/bomb
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `/` from form action. It skip the `context` `path` of `servlet`.

```
<body>
 <form action="bomb" method="get">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
 </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Bang on. If i got it right, it means when i was writing `/bomb` i was telling the ROOT search for servlet map to ROOT/bomb . Was that the case. By ROOT i means server's ROOT